# JavaScript While-Loop not Working

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I was trying to make a text adventure game when I encountered many problems. This was expected since I am fairly new to JavaScript, as well as coding in general. One of the problems I encountered was one where I added some code to prevent the possibility of someone not choosing something. No matter what input I gave the prompt window, it just became unresponsive.

Here's the code that I think is responsible:

```
var weapon = prompt("(prompt text)");
while (weapon != "axe" || weapon != "bow and arrow" || weapon != "rubber chicken"); {
    alert("That's not an option!");
    weapon = prompt("(prompt text)");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (weapon != "axe" ... weapon != "rubber chicken");
```

The main problem is the `;` at the end. It says the `while` loop has only one statement and `;` is that statement. It is similar to doing

```
while (weapon != "axe" ... weapon != "rubber chicken") {
    ;
}
```

Just remove that `;`, you should be fine.

**Note:** Since you want to allow only those three values, the condition should have been with the `&&` operator

```
while (weapon != "axe" && ... && weapon != "rubber chicken") {
    ...
}
```

When you use `||` operator, if I input `weapon` as `rubber chicken`, since it doesn't match `axe` the condition will be satisfied and you will be asking the same question again and again. When you use `&&` operator, it will be truthy only when the value is not equal to all the three values you are comparing.